# Is there anyway to use an empty icon and get rid of dafault icon from the wx.Frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

I know that wxpython does not have the option of getting rid of the default icon of wx.Frame without disabling Close/Maximize/Minimize buttons. But I wonder if there is any way to use an empty icon and hide the default icon from the mainframe? I can not come up with any and if there is any way to do it, would anyone please let me know? or if there is any other idea or a way to hide the default icon, I would appreciate if you could let me know.

I had tried inserting the following code but it did not work.

```
    bmp1 = wx.EmptyIcon()
    # Setup
    icon1 = wx.Icon(bmp1)
    self.SetIcon(icon1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me on windows 10 on wxpython 4.1a

```
import wx


def create_invis_icon():
    frame = wx.Frame(None)

    bmp = wx.Bitmap(32, 32)
    # the default bitmap color is black, make it transparent
    bmp.SetMaskColour(wx.BLACK)
    icon = wx.Icon(bmp)
    frame.SetIcon(icon)
    frame.Show()


app = wx.App()
create_invis_icon()
app.MainLoop()
```